# Django: How to remove ":" from label_tag in django template?

Tags: django-templates

I have a form in my django template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <div class="row"><div class="col-12 col-md-6">{{ field.label_tag }}</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">{{ field }}</div></div><br>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Each label is displayed as follows:
label:

How do I remove the colons?

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can add prettylabel like this;

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <div class="row"><div class="col-12 col-md-6">{{ field.label_tag|prettytable }}</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">{{ field }}</div></div><br>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```